# synchronise on outer class object

Tags: java, multithreading

Hello, I have runnable inner class. Outer class waits inner class notification. After notification is done I need outer class to read some inner class object state params. For this reason I make sleep inner class and wait for outer class read parameters and send notification. For this reason I need synchronise on outer class object.

How to get outer class object from inner class?

Answer (score 3):

If outer class is called `Outer` and inner class is `Outer.Inner`, then you can get your outer instance with:

```
Outer.this
```

when in the inner scope.

You can call methods and access fields this way, but you cannot assign to Outer.this.